# Какие есть тонкости в понимании системных переменных в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.

Вопрос по mysql. Дошел до переменных и хранимых процедур. Вот источник http://xn----9sbcmrygis2b.xn--p1ai/mysql/ANSI_diff_Triggers.html. Понял, что есть два вида переменных: пользовательские переменные и переменные хранимой процедуры / функции. Эти переменные программист создает руками. Пользовательские переменные выдны внутри процедуры / функции, но переменные хранимой процедуры / функции снаружи не видны. То есть, понятие scope в mysql также работает + должны еще быть, по идее, пространства имен (как и в других языках программирования) глобального кода и локального кода процедуры / функции. **Как устроены пространства имен в mysql?**

Не понимаю про системные переменные. Пишут, что сервер MySQL, поддерживает большое количество системных переменных с помощью которых можно сделать, так называемую, "тонкую настройку". Получить полный список системных переменных в консольном клиенте mysql, можно с помощью команды SHOW VARIABLES;

Пишут, что есть два типа системных переменных: специфичные для потока (или для соединения; мы их в дальнейшем называем потоковыми переменными для краткости), которые уникальны для данного соединения и глобальные перемененные, которые предназначаются для управления глобальными событиями. Глобальные переменные также используются для того, чтобы установить значения по умолчанию для соответствующих потоковых переменных для новых соединений.

**Мне это не понятно - зачем системные переменные разделили на сессионные и глобальные системные переменные?**

**Зачем вообще эти системные переменные придумали ,если можно залезть в my.ini и все настроить?**

**Какое место (где лежат) эти системные переменные занимают в пространстве имен?**

Не получается "разложить по полочкам" что где лежит в mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Мне это не понятно - зачем системные переменные разделили на сессионные и глобальные системные переменные?

Чтобы при необходимости можно было для сессии изменить их значения (например, кодировку данных или там уровень изоляции). Согласись, что для каждых настроек создавать свой инстанс сервера как бы расточительно...

> Зачем вообще эти системные переменные придумали ,если можно залезть в my.ini и все настроить?

А откуда, по-твоему, берутся значения глобальных переменных? кое-что прописано хардкодом, конечно, но ведь не всё тебя устроит, как сделано по умолчанию...

> Как устроены пространства имен в mysql?

Да собсно есть глобальное пространство, единое для сервера - там лежат глобальные переменные. Есть пространство сессионное, единое для сессии - там лежат переменные сессии и пользовательские переменные. И есть локальное пространство процедуры/функции, где лежат локальные переменные, в т.ч. и переменные-параметры.

Comment: Ну в общем, нет ничего особенного. Всё просто и совершенно стандартно.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. интересно получается. есть аж три пространства имен - глобальное, сессионное и пространство имен процедуры / функции

Comment: "для каждых настроек создавать свой инстанс сервера как бы расточительно" - что такое инстанс сервера?

Comment: Это ещё один экземпляр сервера (процесс, служба) в той же копии ОС. Как можно запустить несколько копий прикладного софта, так в принципе и со службами, в т.ч. и с сервером MySQL (с той лишь разницей, что их нужно будет настроить так, чтобы они не мешали друг другу).

Comment: а функции встроенные и пользовательские функции в каком пространстве имен лежат?

Comment: Встроенные функции и подключенные UDF лежат в глобальном скопе, пользовательские - в скопе схемы (см. INFORMATION_SCHEME.ROUTINES).

Comment: так сколько всего пространств имен есть? я теперь запутался.  глобальное, сессионное и пространство имен процедуры / функции + еще пространство имен схемы появилось

Comment: То, что таблицы или там вьювы находятся в пространстве схемы - тоже новость? нет, обыденность... а чем таким особенны функции, что их помещение в этот скоп вызывает удивление?

Comment: я не представляю, как таблица хранится в плане пространства имен. в самой таблице на жестком диске есть только шапка таблицы. а сами данные лежат в файле ibdata1. таблица - это просто данные. это даже не переменные.

Comment: Есть данные. Есть структура. А есть просто знание, что таблица с таким именем существует. Первое в файле данных. Второе в файле структуры. А третье - в пространстве имён скопа базы данных. А ещё - ну уж совсем чтобы тебе голову свернуть - есть всякоразные права и абилки на эту таблицу. Свои для каждой учётной записи. И тоже где-то...